# Website mockups in 4k

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, retina

I've recently invested in a 4k monitor, which is brilliant and all, especially for image editing, however I'm finding it a bit frustrating trying to mockup websites due to the difference in resolution.

Is there a way to compensate for the difference in DPI? At present a full 1920x1080 document is 1/4 the size of my screen. I also find myself making things larger to compensate, meaning my work comes out looking silly and oversized when viewed on a standard HD monitor.

I know it wouldn't make too much difference at the front end stage if built using % widths and rem etc, but for client mockups it's not really suitable to start the front end build before signing off on the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things you can do:

1. **Zoom in**. Just scale your design up to 200%. The resolution will be lower, but you will see it at actual size.
2. **Design at 4K, export at 1080**. Just export all your files at half res, but design so your clients can see it at actual size.
3. **Change the monitor to 1080** at least while you design these projects. Yes, you get less screen real estate, but at least on a mac, you actually get sharper, retnia text and graphics in the UI when your 4K monitor is set to HD, which looks great.

Comment: Thanks mate, so in suggestion 2, you would design a full width HD desktop at 3840px wide @72 dpi? and then save up with a width of 1920 px ?

Comment: Yup. You may have to cheat a few of the assets -  enlarge them by 2x - but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a mac, some programs will give you the option to select 'Launch in Low Resolution Mode' if you right click on the application and select the 'Get Info' tab.